# write port listener

Tags: c#, sockets

I wrote an application like a sniffer it can listen on a port and show to the user information that transferred between your computer and internet like source and destinations ip.

How can I want to change it to retrieve url address Instead of ip address is it possible? 
I work with sockets.

```
private byte[] byUDPData = new byte[4096];  //Data carried by the UDP packet

    public UDPHeader(byte [] byBuffer, int nReceived)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byBuffer, 0, nReceived);
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);

        //The first sixteen bits contain the source port
        usSourcePort = (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(binaryReader.ReadInt16());

        //The next sixteen bits contain the destination port
        usDestinationPort = (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(binaryReader.ReadInt16());

        //The next sixteen bits contain the length of the UDP packet
        usLength = (ushort)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(binaryReader.ReadInt16());

        //The next sixteen bits contain the checksum
        sChecksum = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(binaryReader.ReadInt16());            

        //Copy the data carried by the UDP packet into the data buffer
        Array.Copy(byBuffer, 
                   8,              
                   byUDPData, 
                   0, 
                   nReceived - 8);
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to reassemble the application-level data and extract the URL from the HTTP request. This is a pretty huge job (as you must replicate the functionality of several protocol layers) and you should seriously consider adapting (or using) an existing tool. Your question reads like "I have a hammer and some 2x4s and I want to build a suspension bridge."

Comment: Not least the fact that http doesn't run over udp...

Answer (score 1):

Usually there's no need to do that. Take a look at [Wire Shark](http://www.wireshark.org/). You can write your own protocol analyzers and other add-ins if you can't find exactly what you need.

Also, take a look at [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/), which lets your application access the same sniffing abilities of Wire Shark.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> url address Instead of ip address

do you mean the dns name? In which case you need to use the dns class and the `Dns.GetHostEntry` method to look up the name from the IP address.

If you're looking for URL information, well then as @David Schwartz said, you're going to have to decode all the data you've captured, which may or may not have a url in it.